# why my updateOne mongodb does not return anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code:

```
    MongoClient.connect(config.mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Err", err)
        cb(-1)
    }
    else {
        var con = db.db('englishAcademy')
        try {
            con.collection("sound").updateOne({"_id": new ObjectID(sndId)}, {
                $set: {
                    "snd_title": info.snd_title,
                    "snd_type": info.snd_type,
                    "snd_url": info.snd_url,
                    "snd_lsnId": info.snd_lsnId,
                    "snd_lvlId": info.snd_lvlId,
                    "snd_order": info.snd_order
                }
            }), (err, doc) => {
                console.log("result")
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    cb(-1)
                }
                else {
                    console.log(doc)
                    let result = 'row affected'
                    cb(doc)
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }


    }
})
```

could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?the updateOne function does not return anything.but my mongo database gets updated.

EDIT :
I have done this so far and it did not worked.could anyone please help?I used assert no success.I used new :true, no success.I used finde and update ,no success

```
            let infor =  {
                "adm_name": info.adm_name,
                "adm_username": info.adm_username,
                "adm_password": info.adm_password
            }
            con.collection("admins").findOneAndUpdate({"_id": new ObjectID(admId)}, {
                $set: infor
            },{new:true} ), (err , result) => {
                console.log("result")
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    assert.equal(err, null);
                    cb(-1)
                }
                else {
                    let result = 'row affected'
                    assert.equal(1, result.result.n);

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ..

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
   {"_id": new ObjectID(sndId)},
     $set: yourData },
     { new: true },
     function (err, documents) {
       res.send({ error: err, result: documents });        
     }
);
```

Now you can return `newData` in cb.

Comment: it wiil set new data as an object in sound collection.Idont want that

Comment: so what you want ?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0633a231b34f19a4110ac3"),
    "snd_title" : "greeting",
    "snd_type" : "podcast",
    "snd_url" : "http://localhost:9000/upload/sound/1/1/1543913890868_1.mp3",
    "snd_lsnId" : "1",
    "snd_order" : "1",
    "snd_lvlId" : "1"
} my collections are like this.i dont want nested objects

Comment: @ShahrzadNazemi So in short this is your new updated data. Am I right ?

Comment: yes.but my problem is not the data which is returned.i dont get any at all.my code does not do anything after this function runs

Comment: @ShahrzadNazemi Have you tried `findOneAndUpdate`. Because I got the data back. I gave you my working code.

Comment: Instead of return `doc` in cd, use one var and store new data and then return that var.

Comment: If still you have issue then it might be possible that you are missing something.

Comment: @ShahrzadNazemi Please update your question and add what you tried with my answer. So I can verify that.

Comment: I did that.but it does not go to cb function.

Comment: @ShahrzadNazemi I have update my answer. Please check it.

Comment: @ShahrzadNazemi it depends on your version. It will work in new version.

Answer (score 0):

> set new: true

```
MongoClient.connect(config.mongoURL, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db)=> {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Err", err)
        cb(-1)
    }
    else {
        var con = db.db('englishAcademy')
        try {
            con.collection("sound").updateOne({"_id": new ObjectID(sndId)}, {
                $set: {
                    "snd_title": info.snd_title,
                    "snd_type": info.snd_type,
                    "snd_url": info.snd_url,
                    "snd_lsnId": info.snd_lsnId,
                    "snd_lvlId": info.snd_lvlId,
                    "snd_order": info.snd_order
                },{new: true}
            }), (err, doc) => {
                console.log("result")
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    cb(-1)
                }
                else {
                    console.log(doc)
                    let result = 'row affected'
                    cb(doc)
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
})
```